# Using an embedded resource URL in AngularJS $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angularjs-resource

So, I have a REST resource along these lines...

```
/api/Dogs
/api/Dogs/1
/api/Dogs/2
...
```

Where a Dog looks like...

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Url: "http://kennelclub/api/Dogs/1",
    Name: "Butch"
}
```

and a second resource like so...

```
/api/Owners
/api/Owners/1
....
```

As a convenience, to get the dogs for an owner I have this method of querying...

```
/api/Owners/1/Dogs/
```

Now, it's trivially easy to get an AngularJS `$resource` to read an owners dogs, as follows...

```
var ownersDogs = $resource("/api/Owners/:ownerId/Dogs/:dogId", { dogId: "@Id" });
var ownersDogs.query({ ownerId: 1 });
```

**Finally, a Question**

I want to make a change to a dog obtained via this URL with magic angular `$save` function...

```
ownersDogs[0].Name = "Barry";
ownersDogs[0].$save();
```

However, there are two problems here...

- this convenience resource url is read only (i.e. doesn't accept PUT/POST).
- Even if it wasn't, I need to re-supply the `ownerId` to the `$get`/`$save` functions on the objects to work correctly.

If I want to edit the dog returned, I need to use the `/api/Dogs/1` url. This both allows read/write, and doesn't require an ownerId. You'll notice that this Url is already embedded in the Dog object returned.

Is there some way I can get the `$save`, `$get`, etc. functions on the returned object to automatically(?) use the Url embedded in the resource? Or at least, is there some way to change the URL that `$save` will use?

Comment: In my opinion when i comes to be too complicated in term of URL i prefer to use my url with $http calls exposing them in a service instead of using $resource. But that's just a matter or tastes. Do you really want to keep up with $resource ?

Comment: `$resource` is a lot cleaner in my opinion. I particularly like the way it returns the object that will be used immediately, and then fills in the object later without the need for any callbacks.

Comment: Yeah i definitely agree with you about this. Kenavoz gave a pretty nice answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom methods to your resource with custom url :

```
var ownersDogs = $resource("/api/Owners/:ownerId/Dogs/:dogId", { dogId: "@Id" },
    {
    'savedog': { method : 'PUT', url: '/api/Dogs/:dogId'}
    }
);
```

Calling it with :

```
ownersDogs[0].$savedog();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize the `$save` in the following way:

```
ownerDogs[0].$save(function(ownerObject, putResponseHeaders) {
    //ownerObject => saved user object
    //putResponseHeaders => $http header getter
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to make use of the Url parameter in the returned resource, but I solved the problem in a different way. You can simply specify different URLs for the save, etc. operations as follows...

```
var ownersDogs = $resource("/api/Owners/:ownerId/Dogs/:dogId", { dogId: "@Id" },
    {
        'save': { method: 'POST', url: '/api/Dogs/:dogId'}
    });
```